# reference variable in ngFor not working

Tags: angular2-directives, ngfor

I want to convert following HTML code to Angular code using *ngFor

```
<div>Children: <input type="radio" id="1" name="children" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="this.children"/>1
      <input type="radio" id="2" name="children" [value]="2" [(ngModel)]="this.children"/>2
      <input type="radio" id="3" name="children" [value]="3" [(ngModel)]="this.children"/>3
      You have {{this.children}} children
      </div>
```

Angular code

```
<div>Children: <input *ngFor = "let option of selectOptions" type="radio" id=option name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children"/>{{option}}
        You have {{this.children}} children
      </div>
```

selectOptions is defined in Component's class as follows:

```
selectOptions:Array<number>=[1,2,3]
```

I can see error for `{{option}}` that `Angular: Identifier 'option' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member`

I also see error for `id=option name="children"` that `tag start is not closed`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code like this:

```
<div>Children: <input *ngFor = "let option of selectOptions" type="radio" id={{option}} name="children" [value]=option />{{option}}
        You have {{this.children}} children
</div>
```

It worked with this result:

[image]

Generated this html:

[image]

Comment: Yes but I also need 1,2,3 labels with radio button. They are missing. {{option}} isnt working

Comment: It seems one issue is that `option` goes out of scope once `input` tag is closed. If I move `*ngFor` to `div` then I get the labels. But they are now displayed vertically, not horizontally. Do I need to create a CSS to make the radio box horizontal? This code works `<div *ngFor = "let option of selectOptions"> 
        <input  type="radio" [id]="option" name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children">{{option}}      
      </div>`

Comment: This worked. Instead of repeating `div`, I repeated `label`. `label` wraps the input so `option` is in scope of `input` - `<div > 
        <label *ngFor = "let option of this.selectOptions; let ind=index">
        <input  type="radio" [id]="option" name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children"> {{option}}
        </label>
      </div>`

Comment: You can use `<ng-container>` as a logical container for your loop without impacting the DOM.

Comment: thanks. this works `<div >
      Children:     
         <ng-container *ngFor = "let option of this.selectOptions">
        <input  type="radio" [id]="option" name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children"/> {{option}}
        </ng-container>
       You have {{this.children}} children
      </div>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems one issue is that option goes out of scope once input tag is closed. If I move *ngFor to div then I get the labels. But they are now displayed vertically, not horizontally. This code works but with vertical alignment `<div *ngFor = "let option of selectOptions"> <input type="radio" [id]="option" name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children">{{option}} </div>`

For horizontal alignment, this worked. Instead of repeating div, I repeated label. label wraps the input so option is in scope of input - `<div > <label *ngFor = "let option of this.selectOptions; let ind=index"> <input type="radio" [id]="option" name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children"> {{option}} </label> </div>`